# How can I use TradingChart without volume data?

Tags: graphics, charts, finance

I am trying to use the Mathematica Function [`TradingChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TradingChart.html) to produce a chart. I am using data produced by me for the plot and I do not have the volume data.

[Here is my data.](https://hatebin.com/thwbdqqvcy)

`TradingChart` needs data formatted like this: `{{time},{o,h,l,c,v}}`

My temporary solution has been to plug a 0 for the volume value in every entry.

Does a more elegant solution exist?

Comment: Are you using `TradingChart` because you want to use other indicators, or would `CandlestickChart` serve your purposes?

Comment: Hi Brett, my first choice was ```CandlestickChart``` but as you said i need to use some indicators and as far as i know they are not implemented on ```CandlestickChart```.

Comment: In that case I think your filling in a dummy value for volume is the best approach.  I'd use a positive number instead of 0.  Some of the indicators may divide by the volume.  (Which means they may not be suitable for your data, but using 1 or 100 for the volume should generally be safer.)